# How to Connect and Read Tags Value with lib60870.NET library in C#

Tags: c#, scada

I can connect to IEC104 with this code below.

```
Connection con = new Connection("172.30.1.92", 2404);
con.Connect();
```

for reading data , I found this code

```
con.SendReadCommand(24800, 9401);
```

with the above code I can connect but I don't know how to read value

IPAddress,Port,ca and ioa set correctly

Comment: Have you tried to take a look into the documentation? https://github.com/mz-automation/lib60870.NET/blob/master/user_guide_dotnet.adoc